# is there a way to filter words in a sentence, then bold them?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, split

Is there a way to bold certain words of a sentence in an object array? I thought about making like tags, then bolding those tags somehow? I am using React by the way. I am not sure of the logic on when to bold them but it makes more sense to me to identify the words in my data file..The goal is to be able to render the tags i choose as bolded from the given text in my data. So welcome and audience should show bold.

```
//decide on the bolded words//
const tags = ["Welcome", "Audience"];

//somehow bold the words///
function formatted() {
  tags.map((tag) => {
    return <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{tag}</span>;
  });
}
```

MY DATA

```
const Data = [
  {
    index: 0,
    title: "Title 1",
    layout: "wide",
    content: [
      {
        type: "paragraph",
        text: "Welcome the the course.",
      },
      {
        type: "paragraph",
        text: "The purpose of this training is to provide an overview.",
      },
    ],
    image: demo,
    width: imageSize,
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    title: "Title 2",
    layout: "standard",
    content: [
      {
        type: "paragraph",
        text: "The target audience for this course is anyone.",
      },
      {
        type: "paragraph",
        text: "Successful completion of this course is required.",
      },
    ],
    image: demo2,
    width: imageSize,
  },
]
```

```
//Or maybe alternatively bold them using innerhtml???//

//PARAGRAPH
  function Paragraph({ text, size }) {
    const formatted = text.replace(/(the word)/g, (it) => `<b>${it}</b>`);
    return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: formatted }}></span>;
  }
```

Comment: the one you proposed in `Paragraph` is one way. Instead of making a component, you might just make a function `getHighlighted(text)` which produces the highlighted html based on a text. However this might be quite heavy and you have to apply this to all components that output text. So maybe the best way is to make a _DOM_ change like in the old way, search around some browser plugin you should find it.

Comment: I think I will use my paragraph function and add a tag propety to the data file right below text property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit your `MyData` file, one option might be using the [react-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown) library.  You would then be able to put `**Double Astorisks**` around the word you would like in bold then just do:

```
//your component
...
return (
<ReactMarkdown>
   {stringFromDataFile}
</ReactMarkdown> 
)
```

You also have the benefit of having other markdown options like header, links, etc...

---

**If you don't want to use external libraries** you could also do something like this and avoid `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

**My Data**

In your data file, surround the objects you would like to have in bold with any specific key.  I will use `**`.

ex:

```
content: [
   {
      type: "paragraph",
      text: "**Welcome** the the course.",
   },
   {
     type: "paragraph",
     text: "The purpose of this training is to provide an overview.",
   },
],
```

now you can just do:

```
const data = myData.split('**');

const boldOffset = myData.startsWith('**') ? 0 : 1; 

return (
 <>
   data.map((string, index) =>{
      // if we started with bold value
      if(boldOffset === 0){
        return (<span style={{ fontWeight: index % 2 === 0 ? "bold" : undefined }}>{string}</span>);
      }else
        return (<span style={{ fontWeight: index % 2 > 0 ? "bold" : undefined }}>{string}</span>);
   });
 </>
)
```

If we split the data using the key (**) that defines bold values, we know that every other value is bold.  We then just need to check if the first value is bold or not.

Comment: Well i think i will edit my data file a bit but will use my paragraph function too

Comment: @lache I added an additional option to my answer that might suit you better

Comment: nice thank you , i was adding a tag to every object to do it earlier

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer but getting close, if anyone has a better example please post. It doesn't work yet but i maybe need to use spread operator? i will post when closer as no one has posted an example yet.

```
      {
        type: "paragraph",
        tags: ["Welcome", "course"]
        text: "Welcome the the course.",
      },
      {
        type: "paragraph",
        text: "The purpose of this training is to provide an overview.",
      },
```

```
 function Paragraph({ text, size, tags }) {
    const formatted = text.replace(`${tags}`, (it) => `<strong>${it}</strong>`);
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: formatted }} style={{ 
    fontSize: size }} />;
  }
```